# How to unscramble my account?

Tags: support, login, private-beta

I got an error saying it was logged and suggested I post here.

Somehow, my login is all messed up.

First symptom was I could not login to new beta sustainability.stackexchange.com when I got home, having created account at work.  When I went there, it first would not be log in till I used beta link, then when I did, the Google login did nothing.  (Also facebook and yahoo buttons do nothing on sustainability site.)  So I created a openId account and that worked, but it made a new account at sustainability, so I deleted that account and associated my openId with my existing profile, then tried to login again, but again new account, deleted it again.

Then somehow I got the error that said it was logged and suggested posting on meta.

How can I get google login to work on sustainability?

How can I get openId to not create a new account on sustainability?

Comment: *[head spins]*.

Comment: Can anyone reading this see the logged error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When I went there, it first would not be log in till I used beta link

That part is by design. You have to use the link from the invitation email from every new device you want to log in from while the site is in private beta. So long as you use the same login credentials as usual, it should all just work. (I had no trouble using "log in with Stack Exchange" earlier today, though this is obviously anecdotal.)

Your profile on the Sustainability site says you were last seen 38 minutes ago, so I assume you got the login working eventually?

I only see one account with your email or login credentials and as far as I can tell it should all be working properly.

If you're still running into issues, it's probably best to drop us a line via https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/help.